# Spring Integration with RESTEasy

Tags: jboss, spring-integration, resteasy

In our existing integration, we are planning to replace Queue  ( the entry point to our integration processing) with RESTEasy services.

We are processing the HTTP requests as below:

1) Asynchronous HTTP Request Processing for GET 
2) Asynchronous Job Service for POST

I understand that spring integration provides  and  for HTTP requests. But this is not something we want, as the request processing is handled by RESTEasy.

Software stack:
RESTEasy 3.0.9 Framework
Spring Integration 4.1.2.RELEASE
JBOSS EAP 6.4.

Is there a component that we could use to integrate RESTEasy services with spring integration ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Use  <int:gateway> to do the integration with spring. 

    <int:gateway id="providerGateway" service-interface="com.stack.overflow.TestInterface"
        default-request-channel="requestChannel">
        <int:method name="getDataByID" request-channel="requestChannel"/>
        <int:method name="postDataByID" request-channel="requestChannel"/>
    </int:gateway>

Where com.stack.overflow.TestInterface is the Resource Interface see below:

    @Path(RestConstants.SERVICES)
    public interface TestInterface {

    @Path(RestConstants.TEST1)
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getDataByID();



    @Path(RestConstants.TEST2)
    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN  })
    public Response postDataByID(String edi);

}

You can have different message channel if desired (see the gateway above)  for a request. e.g. a request to getDataByID, will be put on the  requestChannel. You can read from this channel and do the required processing as you require and then send a response back.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit component exist, it is all API work to be done. You need to use dependent jar files and integration code

Below are the minimal Jar files to be path in workspace environment using ant or maven:

```
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.0.10.Final
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-spring:3.0.10.Final
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.2.RELEASE
org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.0.10.Final
```

Following listener entries in web.xml to be done:

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/project</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
    <listener- class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTEasyService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.concretepage.Application</param-value>
     </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>RESTEasyService</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/project/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Dispatch Servlet can be put into WEB-INF

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.concretepage" />
</beans>
```

Sample Java Service Code:

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Path("/manage" )
@Component
public class ExService {
    @Autowired
    private ExRepository repository;

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getEmp(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        Map<String,String> map = repository.getEmpDetail(id);
        return Response.ok(map).build();
    }
}
```

For more detail You may refer to http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Spring_Integration

Comment: I'm aware of how RestEasy can be integrated with Spring MVC. The issue I'm facing is to find a way to expose the existing RestEasy Service API. I want to reuse not rewrite the existing API with Spring Integration.  Ideally somehow consume the HTTP requests from RESTEasy and forward it to Spring Integration layer.  e,g, have an inbound adapter for these HTTP requests in spring integration layer.

Comment: I did quite a bit of reading .. and looks like messaging gateway could do the work.. I will try to do a POC to make sure that our requirements are met!!

Comment: Existing RestEasy api can be used unless they are deprecated. I believe that you need to just update the configuration and api. 
The complete of deprecation is http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.2.Final/javadocs/deprecated-list.html

Comment: Looks like my question was not understood. I'm was talking about using RESTEasy services with Spring integration that's all.  I was able to use the <int:gateway> to do the integrations. Thanks!

Comment: I completely understand your question in short you asked, "Is there a component that we could use to integrate RESTEasy services with spring integration ?"
Answer was no. If you could ask for any specific plugin then this could be answered well before.
Any if you have already got the answer then good.